Issue: Spark-Solr Connection Stalling with No Errors on Execution - CDP 7.1.9
We're attempting to execute a basic Spark job to read/write data from Solr, using the following environment:
CDP version: 7.1.9
Spark: Spark3
Solr: 8.11
Spark-Solr Connector: opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK3/lib/spark3/spark-solr/spark-solr-3.9.3000.3.3.7191000.0-78-shaded.jar

When we try to interact with Solr through Spark, the execution process hangs indefinitely, without any errors or results. Other components, such as Hive and HBase, integrate smoothly with Spark, and we’re using a valid Kerberos ticket that successfully authenticates with other Hadoop components. Additionally, we’ve tested REST API calls to Solr via both curl and Python’s requests library, and we’re able to retrieve data with the Kerberos ticket.
The problem appears isolated to Spark’s connection with Solr, as all other systems interact as expected. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have ideas on what might be causing this?
Here’s the Spark code we’re trying:
solr_options = {
    "zkhost": "zkURL-01.orgis.ie:2181,zkURL-02.orgis.ie:2181,zkURL.orgis.ie:2181/solr",
    "collection": "collection_phoectic_test2"
}

# Read data from Solr
df = spark.read.format("solr").options(**solr_options).load()
df.show()

Interestingly, if I specify a non-existent Solr collection, I get an error stating that the collection doesn’t exist. This leads me to believe that Zookeeper is managing the initial connection, as it has the metadata for the Solr collections. However, it seems the Spark executor might be connecting to Zookeeper but failing to establish a connection between Spark executor nodes and Solr nodes.
Additional Details:
The Spark UI logs (stderr) do not provide much insight, and I’m looking for any common troubleshooting steps or configurations that might resolve this.
If anyone has suggestions or has resolved a similar issue, please let me know. Thank you!
spark error logs:

DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /solr/collection_phonectic_test2_shard1_replica_n1/select HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Solr[org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient] 1.0[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 652[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: worker-02.xx:8985[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 >> "q=*%3A*&rows=5000&qt=%2Fselect&fq=_version_%3A%5B*+TO+1812630352655548416%5D&fq=%7B%21hash+workers%3D2+worker%3D0%7D&collection=collection_phonectic_test2&fl=address%2Cmade%2Ccategory%2Ccompanyname%2Cuserfeedback&distrib=false&start=0&sort=id+asc&partitionKeys=_version_&cursorMark=*&wt=javabin&version=2"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 401 Authentication required[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; base-uri 'none'; connect-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; font-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; img-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self'; worker-src 'self';[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate[\r][\n]"
 DEBUG http.wire: [Executor task launch worker for task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)]: http-outgoing-0 << "Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Secure; HttpOnly[\r][\n]"


Just guessing -- if it "hangs indefinitely", perhaps executors are waiting for interactive login, i.e. they are not aware or unable to follow your jaas.conf? Perhaps you can try adding --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true" to get more info in executor logs

There is nothing much i could see after adding these. I could see Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth=; Secure; HttpOnly     | not sure haddop.auth need to be set something when spark executor task trying to connect to solr server.
